# How to get the secret certificate from C# in a Service Fabric application on Unix?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

I have the following in my applicationmanifest.xml:

```
  <Principals>
    <Users>
      <User Name="IdentityService" AccountType="NetworkService" />
      <User Name="ExplorerService" AccountType="NetworkService" />
    </Users>
  </Principals>
  <Policies>
    <SecurityAccessPolicies>
      <SecurityAccessPolicy ResourceRef="IdentityCert" PrincipalRef="IdentityService" ResourceType="Certificate" />
      <SecurityAccessPolicy ResourceRef="IdentityCert" PrincipalRef="ExplorerService" ResourceType="Certificate" />
    </SecurityAccessPolicies>
  </Policies>
  <Certificates>
    <SecretsCertificate X509FindValue="[IDENTITY_SERVICE_THUMBPRINT]" Name="IdentityCert" />
  </Certificates>
```

On Windows clusters, I have been using the thumbprint to look up in localmachine

```
X509Certificate2 cert = X509.LocalMachine.My.Thumbprint.Find(options.Thumbprint, validOnly: false).FirstOrDefault();
```

without problems.

When deploying to a Unix cluster, I faced the following exception:

```
 Unix LocalMachine X509Store is limited to the Root and CertificateAuthority stores. Unix LocalMachine X509Store is limited to the Root and CertificateAuthority stores.
```

I do understand what it is telling me; I can't use LocalMachine. But just to get this right, how would I locate the `X509Certificate2` certificate on the Unix machines? (Is it a .NET Core or Service Fabric thing?)

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-configure-certificates-linux):

> Service Fabric generally expects X.509 certificates to be present in the **/var/lib/sfcerts** directory on Linux cluster nodes. This is true of cluster certificates, client certificates, etc. In some cases, you can specify a location other than the var/lib/sfcerts folder for certificates.

and..

> Certificates specified in the application manifest, for example, through the SecretsCertificate or EndpointCertificate elements, **must be present** in the ***/var/lib/sfcerts*** directory. The elements that are used to specify certificates in the application manifest do not take a path attribute, so the certificates must be present in the default directory. These elements do take an optional ***X509StoreName*** attribute. ***The default is "My", which points to the /var/lib/sfcerts directory on Linux nodes***. Any other value is undefined on a Linux cluster. We recommend that you omit the X509StoreName attribute for apps that run on Linux clusters.

I haven't done SF Linux in a while, so I don't have any script or snippet to help, but the docs should be straight forward.

Comment: So, to clarify, should `var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);` (from [the Windows-specific docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-dotnet-app-enable-https-endpoint#configure-kestrel-to-use-https)) instead be `var store = new X509Store();` or `var store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.LocalMachine);`? Neither seems to be working for me with an ARM-deployed certificate in an Azure Service Fabric cluster on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs on Service Fabric Linux certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-configure-certificates-linux#location-and-format-of-x509-certificates-on-linux-nodes) are wrong - at least for a .NET Core service, `StoreLocation.LocalMachine + StoreName.My` provides no access to the cert files located at `/var/lib/sfcerts`. The docs may be correct for certificates used by the Service Fabric infrastructure, but they are misleading and plain wrong for SF services that require access to certificates.

The [.NET Core document which acts as a public spec for X509Store support on Linux](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/cross-platform-cryptography.md) explicitly states that a `new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine)` results in a `CryptographicException`, which is consistent with the original post and my experience.

So, you'll have to come up with an alternate approach to obtain the certificates. Two approaches seem viable to me:

1. Copy the cert files to a location where the SF service account can pick them up on startup, and either read them directly, or write them to `new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)` for subsequent use. You can [use a `SetupEntryPoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-run-script-at-service-startup) that runs as a user with `AccountType="LocalSystem"` to run the `SetupEntryPoint` as root on Linux. root is needed to read the files from `/var/lib/sfcerts`.
2. Obtain the certificate from another source, eg KeyVault. To secure this, you'll probably want to [use the new Service Fabric support for Managed Service Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/how-to-managed-identity-service-fabric-app-code#accessing-key-vault-from-a-service-fabric-application-using-managed-identity).

Bottom line: It's definitely not trivial to obtain certificates from a Service Fabric service on Linux.

Comment: PS: I opened https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/38819 to fix the docs, some updates may appear there.